# choosing two pairs from a set such that the pairs are not the same thing

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Given a set $A=\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}$, how many ways are there to choose a subset of size $4$ of this set and then choose two pairs of numbers from the subset such that there does not exist two pairs with the same element?

I think the number of choosing such subsets is $\binom{5}{4}$ , but how we can pick  those two pairs such that they are not the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to label the pairs as "*the first pair*" and "*the second pair*" and order within the pairs themselves doesn't matter... then this is effectively going to be the same as arranging the letters of the word FFSSN, where an F in a spot corresponds to the corresponding number for the index appearing in the first pair, an S corresponds to the corresponding number being in the second pair, and the N for the corresponding number appearing in neither.

To count, you can use this interpretation and use multinomial coefficients to jump to the answer of $\binom{5}{2,2,1}=\frac{5!}{2!2!1!}$

Alternatively, you can do the same by first choosing the four elements for the 4-element subset, then choosing two of the elements from those chosen to form the "first" 2-element subset, leaving the remaining two to form the second, giving a total of $\binom{5}{4}\times\binom{4}{2}$, which you will find is equal to what we had before.

---

Now... if instead you *don't* care which pair was "first", you could make a division by symmetry argument, and say that of the arrangements described above, we doublecounted everything... once when a particular pair was the "first" pair and another the "second" pair, and again when those labels were reversed.  Dividing by two will correct the count.

If you want to avoid division by symmetry arguments, then instead begin as we had by first choosing which four elements are in the 4-element subset.  Then... among those elements, whatever they happened to be, one of them will happen to be the "smallest."  Choose what other element will be paired with it.  The remaining elements will form the other pair.

This gives a total of $\binom{5}{4}\times 3$, which you will see is equal to half of the answer from the first interpretation.

Comment: there is a very very basic problem that I don't get that, why actually we "divide' and we don't "subtract"?

Comment: @user715522 This can be phrased in analogy to shepherds in a field.  Now... sheep a very fluffy and it can be hard to distinguish their bodies, yes?  But their legs aren't covered in as much wool.  If a shepherd wants to count how many sheep there are in a group, rather than counting how many bodies there are he can do so indirectly by instead counting the number of *legs* that he can see.  Knowing that every sheep has exactly four legs, had he counted a total of $L$ legs, then the number of sheep must be $\frac{L}{4}$.

Comment: In the same way, if we want to count a scenario, but we have difficulty avoiding counting the same thing multiple times... so long as we know that we had overcounted each object the same number of times, having counted each and every object exactly $c$ times each, and our total count overall including those overcounted $N$ times each, then the corrected count would be $\frac{N}{c}$ which would have been the correct intended count had we counted each object only once rather than $c$ times.

Comment: Let $A=\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}$, now I want to have a partial equivalence relation on A ,I choose one of the conditions that the relations is not reflexive, for example $\left\{\left(2,2\right)\left(3,3\right)\left(4,4\right)\left(5,5\right)\right\}$ then I want to choose two pairs of numbers from $\left\{2,3,4,5\right\}$, such that the two pairs are different ,one of the possibilities to do that is $\left\{\left(2,2\right)\left(3,3\right)\left(4,4\right)\left(5,5\right),\left(2,3\right),\left(3,2\right),\left(4,5\right),\left(5,4\right)\right\}$, but how many other possibilities are there?

Comment: I mean if we fix $\left\{\left(2,2\right)\left(3,3\right)\left(4,4\right)\left(5,5\right)\right\}$, then how many ways are there to choose two pairs of numbers from$ \left\{2,3,4,5\right\}$ like as I did for my example?

Comment: You pick "*who $2$ is paired with*" and you have three options.   What you seem to be describing there is the second interpretation in the answer above.  Note, you miss scenarios like $\{(2,3),(2,4),(3,2),(3,4),(4,2),(4,3),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)\}$ where rather than two pairs you have two equivalence classes being a triple and a singleton or where you have only one equivalence class.

Comment: yes that's true, but I check them in other conditions, I've been overthinking about this problem and can you please edit my formula  which is related to this question (I cannot edit that because I don't know how) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526772/new-wrong-recurrence-formula-for-bell-numbers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103847/discussion-between-jmoravitz-and-user715522).